# What is the difference between msExchangeHideFromAddressBook and msExchHideFromAddressLists?

Tags: exchange, ms-office-communicator

I'm trying to set up up AD attributes for some groups to hide them from the OCS/MOC address book. According to this article:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee323528(office.13).aspx

There should be two attributes that control this visibility: msExchangeHideFromAddressBook and msExchHideFromAddressLists.

What are the differences between these attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Technet article is faulty, only the msExchHideFromAddressLists attribute exists in practice.